# Unable to locate jdk9 on Mac OS Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, java-9

I am trying to install libraries of ConceptNet using this command:

```
sudo apt install build-essential python3-pip python3-dev libhdf5-dev libmecab-dev mecab-ipadic-utf8
```

this is the output i get:

```
Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/apt" (-1)
```

I tried locating the "apt" file location but it is not in the folder as shown in the image below:
[image: apt file not in the folder]

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Oracle deprecated 'apt' some time ago and it isn't included in Java 8 or 9

Comment: @greg-449 how can I execute that command without using 'apt'?

Comment: Just to add to greg-449's comment: The `apt` tool was deprecated in JDK 7 and removed in JDK 8. It's replacement was the javac support for annotation processing and the javax.annotation.processing and javax.lang.model APIs. Hopefully there is a newer version of the product that runs on JDK 8 and newer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on the details as pointed by Alan as well in the comments

The [JSR 269: Pluggable Annotation Processing API](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/proposalDetails?id=269) descibes about the implementation of APIs in JDK to propose the removal of the apt tool as also proposed in [JEP 117: Remove the Annotation-Processing Tool (apt)](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/117)

> The apt annotation processing framework is JDK-specific and dates back
>   to JDK 5. The functionality of the API was standardized with JSR 269,
>   which shipped as part of Java SE 6. In JDK 7, the entirety of the apt
>   API was deprecated.

The release of [JDK8 b27](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7041249) marked this as resolved and since then the `apt` has not been a part of the JDK.

And the [compatibility guide over feature removals](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html#A999476) further details this -

> Use the options available in the javac tool and the APIs contained in
>   the packages `javax.annotation.processing` and `javax.lang.model` to
>   process annotations.

---

To make use of `apt`, you can use software like [Brew](https://brew.sh/), [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) etc which provide apt packaged with them. Then you can use similar command like `brew install ...`

Comment: @user7146946 the command to use after installing brew would be `brew install ....` I hope that's what you are trying. The general instructions are stated in the link shared in answer.